# Develop OpenERP in Eclipse error

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I installed again my openerp project in another machine and added pydev to eclipse then when i going to run openerp-server file below error has come.seems something missing with installing procedure.
please help me to sort out this issue

```
pydev debugger: starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/priyan/Softwares/eclipse/dropins/PyDev 2.7.3/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.3.2013031601/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1397, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/home/priyan/Softwares/eclipse/dropins/PyDev 2.7.3/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.3.2013031601/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1090, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "/home/priyan/Softwares/openerp-7.0/openerp-server.py", line 2, in <module>
    import openerp
  File "/home/priyan/Softwares/openerp-7.0/openerp/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    import addons
  File "/home/priyan/Softwares/openerp-7.0/openerp/addons/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from openerp.modules import get_module_resource, get_module_path
  File "/home/priyan/Softwares/openerp-7.0/openerp/modules/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "/home/priyan/Softwares/openerp-7.0/openerp/modules/graph.py", line 32, in <module>
    import openerp.osv as osv
  File "/home/priyan/Softwares/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import osv
  File "/home/priyan/Softwares/openerp-7.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 28, in <module>
    from psycopg2 import IntegrityError, OperationalError, errorcodes
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

when i use apt get for install it via terminal then error says as below

```
root@priyan-pc:~# sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-psycopg2
root@priyan-pc:~#
```

[image: terminal view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `psycopg2` is not installed in your system. First install `psycopg2` and then run OpenERP server.

Command to  install `psycopg2`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

or

```
sudo easy_install psycopg2
```

or

You can download latest package (tar.gz) from [Download pysycopg2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2). After that extract it, open terminal and run `setup.py` file.

```
sudo python setup.py install
```